# Laravel broken image links in public folder on staging environment. .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I have just deployed a Laravel build to a staging server and am having issues with my URLs to my images folder.

The issue was not present on my local dev environment.

The images on both servers are located in www_root/public/img/ and in the page source are being referenced by /img/xxxx.jpg

As mentioned above, this is all working correctly on local dev but not on my staging environment and the images are not found.

On the staging environment, if I change image links to /public/img/xxxx.jpg they are found but if I do this to local dev it breaks the image refs.

The htaccess at www_root contains:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Rewrite to 'public' folder
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.domain.com$ #on the staging environment, this is updated accordingly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and I have updated my application/config/application.php file accordingly.

Aside from the above 2 changes between environments, everything else is exactly the same.

I can't see anywhere else there could be an issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind for me, is to use URL::asset('link/to/asset.jpg') in your templates.

Because then you create absolute URLs

Comment: No cigar, unfortunately. This gives me the same issue. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When I tried using your provided HTACCESS file, it broke all my links too. Try this one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```